# Jekyll gives an regenerating error when I try saving codes again

Tags: ruby, jekyll

[Jekyll error when I try to save codes again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWd3K.jpg)

```
         C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\ysunmi0427.github.io [master ≡]> bundle exec jekyll serve

         Regenerating: 1 file(s) changed at 2016-06-09 10:53:40 ...done in 1.450617 seconds.

         Regenerating: 1 file(s) changed at 2016-06-09 10:53:42    GitHub Metadata: No GitHub API authentication could be found. Some fields may be missing or have incorrect data....error:

         Error: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed

         Error: Run jekyll build --trace for more information.
```

As you can see, Jekyll automatically regenerates first changes in my code, but fails at the second trial.

I already check Gems. Maybe there is some problem with `jekyll-paginate`. It is well installed (I manually install `gem install jekyll-paginate`, but `jekyll build --trace` gives me an error below.

Dependency Error: Yikes! It looks like you don't have jekyll-paginate or one of its dependencies installed. In order to use Jekyll as currently configured, you'll need to install this gem. The full error message from Ruby is: 'cannot load such file -- jekyll-paginate' If you run into trouble, you can find helpful resources at http://jekyllrb.com/help/!

I tried all versions of Ruby.

Thanks.

Comment: Please don't post the screenshots, but copy and paste the messages from console over here. It seems that your project can't access github metadata. Are you sure you need `jekyll-github-metadata` gem? Try removing that first, if you are not sure that you need it.

Comment: @Mladen Jablanović I tested after seeing your comment, but `jekyll-github-metadata` is one of my dependencies. And thanks for your guide, I'll paste the messages from console.

Comment: Have you set it up according to https://github.com/jekyll/github-metadata

Comment: @Mladen Jablanović Yes. `jekyll-github-metadate` is well installed.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did to resolve this problem:

- Create GitHub personal token ([guide](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-an-access-token-for-command-line-use/))
- Add the `JEKYLL_GITHUB_TOKEN` env variable whose content is the created token
- Download the CA cert file from https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
- Add the `SSL_CERT_FILE` env variable pointing to the download `.pem` file.

I also wrote a blog post about this case [here](https://www.hieule.info/programming/fix-errors-github-metadata-ssl-certificate-running-jekyll-serve/).